# Yii2 - Get action of controller but with url

Tags: yii2

I already use this Yii::$app->controller->action->id to get my current action in controller, but can someone tell me on how to get the url instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get **current** `url`, you can use:

```
Yii::app()->request->url
```

Which will return full requested URL by user.

Answer (score 2):

[Referrer Detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-request.html#$referrer-detail)

You could use `Yii::$app->request->referrer` which returns the last page the user was on.

You need also take into account that referrer can be null with redirect example :

```
return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer ?: Yii::$app->homeUrl);
```